# wrong output when compare two string

Tags: php, string, compare, strcmp

i want to compare 2 ether address.

i tried trim, strcmo and replace null characters. but it doesn't work

here is my code:

```
<?php
$a='0x0c656968912fF22c17ABf5E190498034542CC475';
$b='0x0c656968912ff22c17abf5e190498034542cc475';
$a2 = str_replace("\0", "", $a);
$b2 = str_replace("\0", "", $b);

var_dump($a == $b);
var_dump($a2 == $b2);
var_dump(strcmp($a,$b));
var_dump(strcmp($a2,$b2));
```

it looks all of above var_dump should return true (and 0 in strcmp) but they dont!
why?!
is it a bug?
how can i compare this string

Comment: They are different strings. You have uppercase letters in one and not the other. If you need a case-insensitive comparison then look at [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) or apply `strtolower()`/`strtoupper()` on both strings to make their letters equal.

Comment: The two strings aren't equal. The first contains some upper case letters; the second doesn't.

Comment: @MohammadSalehi My personal definition of programming is 99 failures followed by 1 success so keep trying and don't give up. I will guarantee you that you will not be fooled by this situation in the future.

Comment: Here's a hint: "A" != "a"

Comment: I know this question is not a good one, I didn't delete my question because  I thought someone may occur the same problem. please stop downvoting

Comment: @Chris Well, see Gordon's comment!

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman What about it? Gordon's comment was exactly what the "problem" the OP couldn't figure out. What's confusing about this question that everyone in the comments, including Gordon, were able to figure out? That was my point. The question was put on hold incorrectly. Gordon gave a great hint for the OP to catch his own mistake.

Comment: @Chris Gotcha... So what should be the right way? Put on hold and tell OP what's the mistake? Right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman The right way should be to let people in the comments/answers help the OP correct their mistake.. Right? Just like Gordon and MonkeyZeus have done in the comments and coderodour has done in the Answers. If he hadn't answered the question before being put on hold as you all have marked it, he wouldn't have been able to post the _now_ accepted answer to a question that wasn't unclear in the first place. -- My point is, there isn't anything about this question that needed to be downvoted/put on hold. OP didn't know about the case sensitivity comparison; that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing what is demonstrated in the first example of PHP's documentation of the `strcmp` function [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

Basically, the comparisons are case-sensitive. Therefore, `strcmp` does not return true because the character `F` in the 15 place of `$a` is uppercase, where as it is lowercase in `$b`.

see below, highlighted by underscores:

```
$a='0x0c656968912f_F_22c17ABf5E190498034542CC475';
$b='0x0c656968912f_f_22c17abf5e190498034542cc475';
```

Upon reconsideration, there are other instaces of case-mismatch between the two strings.

Comment: it looks even with `==` it's case -sensitive.

Comment: I have modified my answer to reflect that, after confirming with an online php sandbox. Now to go check why my php scripts don't seem to discriminate between character casing when using that operator. Oh Boy.